# jQuery iterate through input fields and disable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a question I'm trying to figure out...

I have a lot of inputs in a form, but I only need to iterate through the ones in the div with `player` class.

```
<div class="player">
 <input type="text" value="0" class="unit" />
 <input type="text" value="0" class="unit" />
 <input type="text" value="0" class="unit" />
 <input type="text" value="0" class="unit" />
 <input type="text" value="0" class="unit" />
 <input type="text" value="0" class="unit" />
 <input type="text" value="0" class="unit" />
</div>
```

What I need is to iterate through them all once an input field has been modified and calculate how many of the input fields have 0 in them and if its 1 or more than 4 disable submit button.

I've been trying like this but it doesn't seem to work

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(function()
        {
            var $sum = parseInt($("#sum").text(), 10);
            var $num = 0;
            if(($sum == 0))
            {
                $("button[name=submit2]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }

            $(".player input[type=text]").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function()
            {
                $.each($("input[type=text]"),function(){
                    if (!isNaN(+this.value)) 
                    {
                        ++$num;
                    }
                });
                if (($num > 4) || ($num == 1))
                     $("button[name=submit2]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                else
                     $("button[name=submit2]").removeAttr("disabled");
            });
        })      
    });
```

I've also tried

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".unit").each(function() {

                $(this).keyup(function(){
                    CheckNull();
                });
            });
            function CheckNull() {
                var $num = 0;
                $(".unit").each(function() {
                    if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                        ++$num;
                    }
                });
                if (($num > 4) || ($num == 1))
                    $("button[name=submit2]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                else
                    $("button[name=submit2]").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Well, that function is only going to iterate on load. Have you tried making it its own function, and then calling it in the onchange attribute of your input box?

Comment: can you explain what your code returns that makes it not work?

Comment: also why iterate it two times? you can do it also like `$(".player .unit").keyup(function() {...` to prevent using `$.each`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
   ++$num;
}
```

with

```
if($(this).val() != "" && $(this).val() !=0) {
   ++$num;
}
```

to be more jQuery style

Comment: Thanks alot guys, they all helped very nicely.. i missed that onchange function i dont have mutch xp with jquery usualy someone else does that part thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't follow your function, but I believe your problem is that you are running it on page load, and not on the onchange of your input boxes. I achieved the desired functionality by doing that in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/peteTalksWeb/pen/xGvaZX)

html:

```
<div class="player">
<input type="text" value="0" class="unit" onchange="validateChanges()" type="number"/>
<input type="text" value="0" class="unit" onchange="validateChanges()" type="number" />
<input type="text" value="0" class="unit" onchange="validateChanges()" type="number" />
<input type="text" value="0" class="unit" onchange="validateChanges()" type="number" />
<input type="text" value="0" class="unit" onchange="validateChanges()" type="number" />
<input type="text" value="0" class="unit" onchange="validateChanges()" type="number" />
<input type="text" value="0" class="unit" onchange="validateChanges()" type="number" />
</div>
<button name="submit2">Click</button>
```

JS:

```
function validateChanges() {
  var playerDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("player")[0];
  var inputs = playerDiv.getElementsByTagName("input");
  var total = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    total += parseInt(inputs[i].value);
  }
  if(total == 1 || total > 4) { // IF total is 1 or more then 4
    document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].disabled = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].disabled = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a small thing : "i only need to itterate through the ones in player class div"

Comment: Ok, I just updated the codepen to do just the inputs in the player class div

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want :

```js
// control function
function checkInputs() {
    var num = 0;
    // foreach inputs
    $(".player input").each(function(i,item) {
      var value = $(this).val();
      if (value.trim() === "0") {
        num++;
      }
    });
    if (num === 1 || num > 4) {
      $("#myForm input[type='submit']").attr("disabled", "true");
    } else {
      $("#myForm input[type='submit']").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
}
// if you want a first check after loading the page :
checkInputs();

$(".player input").change(
  // This function will be called each time an input change in the player div
  checkInputs
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <div class="player">
   <input type="text" value="0" class="unit" />
   <input type="text" value="0" class="unit" />
   <input type="text" value="0" class="unit" />
   <input type="text" value="0" class="unit" />
   <input type="text" value="0" class="unit" />
   <input type="text" value="0" class="unit" />
   <input type="text" value="0" class="unit" />
  </div>

  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [JsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Webby2014/30fepe8h/)

```
 $(function () {  
    $('.unit').on('change', function () { 
        var units = 0;         
        $('.unit').each(function (index, value) {
            var unit = parseInt($(value).val(),10);
            units += unit;
            if(units >= 4 || units === 1) {
                $('form > button').prop('disabled', true);
            } else {
                $('form > button').prop('disabled', false);
            }         
        }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: he also wants if units is also 1 - `units >= 4 || units == 1 `

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why are you checking the length? `this.value.length!=0`

I tweaked your code, here is the fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/bLa6evpg/

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

looks like i was almost right just messed up a bit Silent_coder fixed this +i added some tricks i saw here

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        CheckNull();
        $(".player input").each(function() {

            $(this).keyup(function(){
                CheckNull();
            });
        });
        function CheckNull() {

            var $num = 0;
            $(".player input").each(function() {

                if(this.value != 0 ) {
                    $num++;
                }
            });  
            if (($num > 4) || ($num <= 1))
                $("button[name=submit2]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            else
                $("button[name=submit2]").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
```

Works like i charm for me ^^